# Contentful: how to change the name of an entry?

Tags: contentful

I am trying to use the Contentful web interface to change the name of an entry.  Attached is a screenshot.  I have searched for 30 minutes for the button that lets me change the title from "untitled" to something else.  Alas, it is nowhere to be found on this horrible, horrible interface.

Where is it?  Does it even exist?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Contentful, the entry titles must be handled by a content model field.

#### In your content model, create a field

[image]

#### Then, tell Contentful to use this field as entry title

[image]

#### Now, you can create a new entry and set the title

[image]